# React: Why are props not frozen?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

React suggests not to mutate props. I was operating under the impression that when props are passed in, they would be immutable or frozen.

The code below does not throw any errors and mutates the prop. Is this a bug?

```
try{
  var a = this.props.a;
  a.push('one')
  a.push('two')
  a.push('three')
  console.log(a)
}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Looks like they are frozen infact https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5c6a496d98b80d19d851c2ec3a56d760b7118a50/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact reasoning behind it or if that's documented somewhere but I could take a guess:

Freezing any assignment to a variable is not easy or even necessarily possible outside of using new-ish or even as of yet unimplemented browser features. Also deep freezing all your props in your app could have performance implications and would certainly need to be removed for prod builds.

***Can you freeze assignment of a primitive variable?*** I don't think so. I think babel does it with `const` by statically checking code at compile time.

***And can you freeze objects without Object.freeze or ES7's proxy?*** Again I don't think so, the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) readme says:

> which you cannot possibly obtain in legacy engines

***What if someone does mutate something?*** These props are shallow copied, meaning you won't affect the parent prop unless you modify a nested object. However even if you did it would't affect the app, as that would get wiped out on the next render (just like your modifications).

If I got something wrong please let me know! This is just my reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanations. One explanation that you may want to look into is regarding mutating something. I was able to successfully mutate an array (pushing items) that got passed in as a prop via redux. My changes were persisted into the redux store and thus this question came about.

Comment: Oh that's interesting - you're definitely not sending them back through an action? I need to check the react source, I remember seeing shallow copying for context and assumed they'd be doing it for props too

Comment: Yes, I was definitely not updating it via any actions and was surprised to notice that the store was updating and persisting my changes. Maybe arrays are treated specially. I didn't try with a regular object.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the same behavior as `const` has, you **can't reassign** the value, but you can still push to the array or add keys to an object because those are not protected. Anyway, despite the possibility to do those mutations, you should not do this.

`this.props.a = [1,2,3];` won't work

`this.props.a.push(123);` will work.

`this.props.a = {name: 'John Doe'}` won't work

`this.props.a.name = 'John Doe'` will work

If you try to **reassign** a prop in your component a type error will occur.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property a ...

Answer (score 0):

It won't throw any error unless you frozen the object(props) explicitly.

Props are received from parents and immutable as far as the Component receiving them is concerned.

i.e React by default the `props` are immutable in the sense it is the concern of your component to maintain them as data received from parent and use as it is. Where as we can use `state` to maintain the local(component level data) that can be changed any time and keeping props contract with the parent.

Answer (score -1):

This is not true. Props are mutable by default. If you're using ES2015 you can make them read-only within your function be doing the following:

`const { a } = this.props; // would create a const variable 'a'.`

Same as:

`const a = this.props.a;`

While you won't be able to *reassign* 'a' now, you can still mutate it. Meaning, `a = 'foo';` will throw an error, but you will still be able to do `a.push('foo');`.

If you want to use immutable data structures, try working with https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper or https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/