# How does React make props read only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering what mechanism they actually use to throw an error when trying to set `this.props.a = 1` or something similar.

I ask because when logging props I don't see anything like `[Getter/Setter]` which I assumed is what they were doing.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641254/react-why-are-props-not-frozen

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5c6a496d98b80d19d851c2ec3a56d760b7118a50/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L168

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks! Do you know the difference between using `Object.freeze` and setting values to be `writable: false`?

Comment: @Yeah `writable: false` means you can't change the property by assignment. Freezing the object means you can't delete, change, or add any properties to the object (but `Object.freeze` is shallow).

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

I think `props` is a kind of Object value which is marked as `const`.

But we can change children in any `Object` value even though it is marked as `const`;

```
// const also works on objects
const MY_OBJECT = {'key': 'value'};

// Attempting to overwrite the object throws an error - Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
MY_OBJECT = {'OTHER_KEY': 'value'};

// However, object keys are not protected,
// so the following statement is executed without problem
MY_OBJECT.key = 'otherValue'; // Use Object.freeze() to make object immutable
```

As you can see above codes, you can use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) function to make object immutable.

I think the `props` value is set as `Object.freeze()`function.